# Applying jquery code to POP OUT MENU

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to create a pop out menu so each time a user hovers over one menu it pops out and changes the icon to the colored one.

Got stock with some codes.

```
$('.box').hover(function() {
if(!$(this).data('open')){
    $(this).animate({ top: '-30px' }, 'slow', function() {});
} else {
    $('#.box').animate({ top: '50px' }, 'slow', function() {});
}
```

});

DEMO HERE: http://jsfiddle.net/6jLFP/4/

Can you share the jsfiddle of your edit with me? I am really stuck now. I also need to hover state (colored icons) active while its moving up or popping out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are near to the answer. I do a few changes:

- One add `position:relative` to your `.box`

  ```
  .box {
     position:relative;
  }
  ```
- Two change your function:

  ```
  $('.box').hover(function() {
     $(this).animate({ top: '-30px' }, 'slow');
   }, function () {
     $(this).animate({ top: '0px' }, 'slow');
   });
  ```

Check this demo **http://jsfiddle.net/6jLFP/21/**

You can do this with CSS too adding this to your CSS file:

```
.box {transition:all 1s ease-in;}
.box:hover {top:-50px;}
```

View this demo **http://jsfiddle.net/6jLFP/27/**. The only issue here is about compatibility.

Comment: Yeah I got it thanks. however I have one more question. How can I make it steady that while it popping out the hover state of the icons are still active I mean they are still colored cause if you're not hovering to the icon itself it wont turn colored.

Comment: You need to change your `:hover` declarations for hover the `.box` like this `.box:hover span.icon.time` Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/6jLFP/38/